# Do Warframe Screenshot settings effect the screenshots that Steam takes?

Tags: steam, warframe

I want to create some Warframe backgrounds, so I went into the settings and remove the UI from screen shots. Does this count when I am taking a screen shot with Steam?

Comment: Why dont you just try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting doesn't affect Steam's screenshots. The HUD will be visible regardless of the setting, assuming you haven't disabled HUD completely.